# Make image scale with parent container when screen is re-sized

Tags: html, css

In my liquid layout, my `div` elements have the property `position-fixed`. This means that as I re-size the browser, all the elements remain in the same position but have shrunk or increased in size.

The problem is when I place a picture in one of my `div` elements, it does not scale to fit in my `div` element, therefore the image 'leaks' out of its `div` container.

What I need: a property on my `div` element and/or image so that the image stays the same size as the `div` container and when the page is re-sized, the image re-sizes as well.  Here's what I have:

```css
#div1 {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  opacity: .3;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: .3;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  top: 10%;
  height: 40%;
  width: 60%;
}

#div3 {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: .3;
  position: fixed;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 40%;
  width: 60%;
}

#div4 {
  background-color: tan;
  opacity: .3;
  position: fixed;
  height: 80%;
  right: 80%;
  width: 20%;
  top: 10%;
}

#div5 {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .3;
  position: fixed;
  height: 80%;
  width: 20%;
  left: 80%;
  top: 10%;
}

#div6 {
  background-color: purple;
  opacity: .3;
  position: fixed;
  top: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
}

img {}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <p>div1</p>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <figure>
    <img class="pictures" src="assets/me.jpg" />
    <figcaption>
      This is a picture.
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

</div>
<div id="div3">
  <header>
    <h1>Introducing Me</h1>
  </header>
  <p>div3</p>
  <p>Hello eveyrone i am adan ramirez</p>
</div>

<div id="div4">
  <p>div4</p>
</div>
<div id="div5">
  <p>div5</p>
</div>
<div id="div6">
  <p>div6</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make image `background-image: url(..img);`

and apply `background-size: cover;` on the same div.

The key here is cover property value as it tells browser to resize image while keeping aspect ratio to fit all sides.

@Sphinxxx suggested to use `background-size: contain;` which solved OP problem;`

Comment: i see what you are trying to do, in applying this code the image fit into the div container, problem is... image is cut off, i need the image width/height 100% while scaling inside the size of container at all times, so this isnt a solution

Comment: Try `background-size: contain;` instead, and probably also `background-position: center;` and `background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: contain along with back-ground-repeat: no-repeat; BINGO! you solved it and thanks so much! gj

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

`object-fit` is a pretty cool CSS3 property.

Used with the `contain` value the image will increase or decrease in size within its container while maintaining its aspect-ratio.

Here's how [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) describes it:

> The `object-fit` property defines how an element responds to the height
>   and width of its content box. It's intended for images, videos and
>   other embeddable media formats in conjunction with the `object-position`
>   property. Used by itself, `object-fit` lets us crop an inline image by
>   giving us fine-grained control over how it squishes and stretches
>   inside its box.

Because [browser support for this property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit) is still somewhat weak, here's a **polyfill** that covers all major browsers including IE9: [Polyfill for CSS object-fit property](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit)

For a deeper look here are a few references:

- [W3C CSS Image Values and Replaced Content Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#the-object-fit)
- [MDN `object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)
- [CSS-Tricks `object-fit](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/)

Comment: didn't know about this property, but as expected bad support http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Comment: it's amazing cause i always felt image tagged needs were overlooked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: yes, and when i re-size the browser, the image leaks out of it's div container

Comment: Does the image actually stay the same size or is it resized?
Does it leak horizontally or vertically (or both)?

Comment: the width is perfect, does not leak and scales with the div, however... the height leaks to begin with and continues to do so when i re-size.

Comment: Do you want the image to be cropped vertically, or scaled down so that it fits in height ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
img {
  max-width: 100%; 
  max-height: 100%;
}
figure {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

figure is the parent element, so you need to set it's height/width as well. Also, the default styling on figure includes a margin, so you need to remove that to keep the image inside of the parent div. Also, you may need to make the max-height smaller to account for the caption if you want to keep that inside of the parent div.

You can also use width and height instead of max-* if you want the image to always fill the parent regardless of its native size.