# Image not staying within container and adjusting footer to contain items neatly

Tags: html, css

I'm new to the site so I hope I'm asking in the right section and in the right way.
I have a site where I have an image under the menu bar. I'm trying to get it to stay within the container and if the image is too big or small it will scale to the container. I've tried max-height:100%; and max-width: 100%; with no luck.

Another issue I'm having is trying to scale the footer to be 20% of the page and to have the contents float neatly inside of it.

I've nearly fixed one problem by changing code to this 
html:

```
<div id="slideshow_container">
<ul> 
<li>
<img src="images/banner_image.jpg" alt="banner1" />
</li> 
</ul>
```

And this CSS:

```
#slideshow_container 
{
    float:inherit;
    max-height: 600px; 
    background: url(../images/banner_image.jpg) repeat-x; 
}
```

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DPMC87/8cxnmxgo/

All help and explanations are really appreciated as I'm busting my head trying to fix it.

```
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/main.css" />
```

```
<div id="header">

    <div class="container">

    <h1><a href="index.html">This</a></h1>

    <div id="main_menu">

        <ul>
            <li class="first_list"><a href="index.html" class="main_menu_first main_current">home</a></li>
            <li class="first_list"><a href="#" class="main_menu_first">about us</a></li>
            <li class="first_list"><a href="#" class="main_menu_first">Design</a></li>
            <li class="first_list with_dropdown">
            <li class="first_list"><a href="#" class="main_menu_first">Gallery</a></li>
            <li class="first_list"><a href="#" class="main_menu_first">Store</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div> <!-- END #main_menu -->

    </div> <!-- END .container -->

</div> <!-- END #header -->

<div id="main_content">

    <div id="slideshow_area">

    <div class="container">

        <div id="slideshow_container">

            <ul>
                <li><img src="images/banner_image.jpg" alt="banner1" /></li>
            </ul>


        </div> <!-- END #slideshow_container -->

    </div> <!-- END .container -->

    </div> <!-- END #slideshow_area -->




    <div id="latest_works">

        <h3>LATEST DESIGNS</h3>



        <div id="carousel_wrapper">

            <ul>
                <li id="work01">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/sample_view.gif" alt="work01" /></a>
                </li>
                <li id="work02">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/sample_view.gif" alt="work02" /></a>
                </li>
                <li id="work03">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/sample_view.gif" alt="work03" /></a>
                </li>
                <li id="work04">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/sample_view.gif" alt="work04" /></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div> <!-- END #carousel_wrapper -->

    </div> <!-- END #latest_works -->

    <div id="bottom_content">

        <div id="news">

            <h3>News</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ut nulla sapien, at aliquam erat. Sed vitae massa tellus. Aliquam commodo
            aliquam metus, sed iaculis nibh tempus id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci
            luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam nec nisi in nisl euismod fringilla.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ut nulla sapien, at aliquam erat. Sed vitae massa tellus. Aliquam commodo
            aliquam metus, sed iaculis nibh tempus id. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci
            luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam nec nisi in nisl euismod fringilla</p>

        </div> 

        <div id="clients">


    </div> <!-- END #bottom_content -->

</div> <!-- END #main_content -->

<div id="footer">

    <div class="container">


        <div id="footer_explore" class="footer_info">

            <h4>explore</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div> <!-- END #footer_about -->

        <div id="footer_browse" class="footer_info">

            <h4>browse</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="contact.html">contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">terms of service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">privacy policy</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div> <!-- END #footer_about -->

        <div id="footer_connect" class="footer_info">

            <h4>connect with us</h4>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com" id="facebook" title="Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="twitter" title="Twitter">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.pinterest.com" id="pinterest" title="Pinterest">Pinterest</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div> <!-- END #footer_about -->
        <br>
        <p id="copyright">&copy; copyright blah blah


    </div> <!-- END .container -->

</div> <!-- END #footer -->
```

Comment: I recently answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32288361/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B The answer I see from you is to add max-height: 100%; or width. Is that the right one to look at? If so I've tried that with no luck.  Maybe I'm adding it to the wrong place? Also the css is in the fiddle.

Comment: I can't offer you more guidance because your fiddle demo isn't working. Try adding the absolute URLs of your stylesheets to the 'External Resources' of the fiddle. Or simply add them above. Relative URLs aren't helpful as we can't access the files (since we don't know your domain).

Comment: @Michael_B When you say absolute URL how do I do that? I don't have a server if that's what you mean. Sorry, limited experience with this...Thank you though :)

Comment: This link contains a relative URL: `href="stylesheets/reset.css"`.
This link illustrates an absolute URL:  `href="https://www.yourdomain.com/stylesheets/reset.css"`.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I do understand what you're telling me but I just can't figure out what the yourdomain.com part should be...

Comment: No need to apologize. But your fiddle demo doesn't replicate the problem in your question, and your code is incomplete because the styles are missing. So it's not really possible to help you. Generally speaking, your question will get more attention and better quality answers if you adhere to the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks very much. I've tried to get all the images in to the fiddle but can't figure out how. The only other style sheet I have is the reset one that it should work without. Is there anyway I could upload all files for you to view? If not I appreciate the help, thanks man!

Comment: I've nearly fixed one problem by changing code which I've added to the post.I have a different problem now with the proper image being beneath the same(larger image) now